Solve Laplace equation in 2D with nonhomogeneous boundary conditions, using Galerkin method
I want to solve Laplace equation:
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=0$$
in the domain $0<x<1$, $0<y<1$, with non-homogeneous boundary conditions $u(x=0,y)=1$ and $u(x=1,y)=u(x,y=0)=u(x,y=1)=0$.
An analytical solution using Fourier series is simple and gives the solution:

Now I want to (approximately) solve it using Galerkin method.
I am following Fletcher's book (Fletcher - Computational Galerkin Methods). I have checked here and here.
I tried writing a code to find the approximate solution, given in the form
$$F_{ij}(x,y)=\sin(i \pi x) \sin(j \pi y)$$
(I tried also with cos, and sin+cos).
and the initial approximation $u_0(x,y) = u_0 = (1-x)$ to satisfy the B.C.
Solution should be
$$ u\approx \sum_i \sum_j a_{ij} F_{ij} + u_0$$
The problem: since the basis function are orthogonal to each other, by the method of weighted residuals, all coefficients are always zero.
I even tried to compute it with the code:
clc; clear;

syms x y real positive
syms i j integer positive

% differential equation
L = @(u) diff(u,x,2) + diff(u,y,2); % linear operator on differential equation
% L = @(u) diff(u,x,2); % linear operator on differential equation
% f = sym(1); % R.H.S.
f = sym(0); % R.H.S.

% boundary location
xl = sym([0 1]);
yl = sym([0 1]);

pi = sym(pi)
F = sin(i*pi*x)*sin(j*pi*y) % trial function


u0 = (1-x)
M = 3;
N = 3;

ii = 1:M;
jj = 0:N;
ij = combvec(ii,jj);

for n=1:size(ij,2)
    phi(n) = subs(F,[i,j],[ij(1,n),ij(2,n)]); % basis functions
end

syms a0

a = sym("a",size(phi));
u = sym(0);
u = u+u0; % initial approximation, to satisfy BC
for n=1:length(a)
    u = u+a(n)*phi(n);
end
u;

% residual
r = L(u)-f+L(u0);

% inner product
inner = @(u,v) int(int(u*v,x,xl(1),xl(2)),y,yl(1),yl(2));

% form linear system of equations for coefficients aij
for n=1:length(a)
    R(n) = inner(r,phi(n)) == 0;
end
R'

a_coef = solve(R,a)

a_coef = struct2cell(a_coef)'
u_a = subs(u,a,a_coef);

I can't find what exactly is wrong here. Perhaps the trial functions are wrong?
How to solve this particular equation, with the given boundary conditions?

If you have an orthogonal basis, the matrix is diagonal (i.e., not all entries are zero -- it's just that the off-diagonal entries are zero). That said, the solution you show does not satisfy the Laplace equation. The sum of second derivatives of what you have is not zero.

Suggestion: Will your code do okay with homogeneous BCs?  Do homogeneous 0 BCs with a right hand side.

@CuteCompute yes, it works with homogeneous BCs. I tried with the equation $u_{xx}+u_{yy} = 1$ and homogeneous BCs, and the answer is correct.

@WolfgangBangerth hummm. I see that now, the proposed solution does not satisfy the  Laplace equation. But why it works analytically by means of Fourier series, and how do I solve it with Galerkin method? By the guidelines in Chapter 1 of Fletcher - Computational Galerkin methods, the trial functions are chosen to satisfy the B.C., but not exactly the differential equation - so we construct an approximate solution. is it not so?

I understand that an approximate solution does not solve exactly the differential equation, so we set the residual $R = L(u)$ and in the Galerkin method, we enforce the residual to be orthogonal to each approximate solution. Solving the linear system of equations for the coefficients $a_{ij}$ gives us the approximate solution for the problem. If we know the solution for the differential to use it as trial functions, then we don't have to look for an approximate solution, right?
